# не срабатывает вызов функции из библиотеки lodash

Tags: reactjs, react-hook, lodash

Не срабатывает вызов функции   car(), также не работает console.log("12132"). Как их правильно вызвать?

https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-wildflower-o7r4bz?file=/src/App.js:139-322

```
  function car() {
    console.log("т12");
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    _debounce(() => car(), 1000);
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    _debounce(() => console.log("12132"), 1000);
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**debounce**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce) сам по себе ничего не вызывает. Он возвращает  [**функцию**](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.15/lodash.js#L10304) с установленным таймером которую нужно вызвать.

```
 function car() {
    console.log("т12");
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const debouncedFn = _debounce(() => car(), 1000);
    debouncedFn();
  });
```

Поправил ваш [**код**](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-currying-kdr0xt?file=/src/App.js)